# Query table, but get a specific id listed first

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table in my database, named "folders".

How do I make a query that output everything but always list a specific ID first?

Lets use ID "12345" for the folder I want to be listed first.

I currently use this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE memberid='$session_userid' ORDER BY name ASC ") or die(mysql_error());
```

I tried to Google it, but nothing comes up and I'm totally blank :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add another `ORDER BY` clause for your special criteria. Any expression that will give one value for your "preferred" record and a second value for all the other records will work.

```
mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM folders
    WHERE memberid='$session_userid'
    ORDER BY IF(id=12345, 1, 2), name ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I tried that, did not output anything, no errors or anything.: mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE memberid='$session_userid'  ORDER BY IF(id=6PRN8Z), name ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @Ken - you need `IF(id=12345, 1, 2)`, not just `IF(id=6PRN8Z)`. And actually you need single quotes around `6PRN8Z` since it's not a plain number

Comment: Ahh, that fixed it. What does `1, 2`    means?

Comment: @Ken - The expression just returns `1` when the condition is true and `2` when it's not. Since the default sort order is `ASC`, this puts records where `id=12345` first. You'd get the same results with `-5` and `1000` or `'A'` and `'Z'`. `1` and `2` just make it clearer what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY FIELD() allows to sort rows by custom values, so this should work:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM folders 
WHERE memberid='$session_userid' 
ORDER BY FIELD( id, '12345' ) DESC , name ASC
```

If you need 2 folders to be listed first (let's say id1='12345' and id2='23456') the query would be

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM folders 
WHERE memberid='$session_userid' 
ORDER BY FIELD( id, '12345' , '23456' ) DESC , name ASC
```

EDITTED: Added "DESC" to the ORDER BY FIELD(). ASC being the default, the folder with id="12345" would be listed last!